# How to get this sql query: show records by amount

Tags: sql

I want to display amount of sales from a table in this format:

```
Sales             qty
------------------------------------------
Sales > 50,000    500
Sales < 2000      200
Sales > 15,000    600
------------------------------------------
```

How can I create this?

I can write a query for one amount `where > 50000`  but in this case there is three 50,000 , 2000, 15,000 and how can I show all this in the result?

Comment: But what do you expect for sales = 10000? Are the sales > 15000 also supposed to include sales > 50000, or just up to 50000?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to simply use `union all`:

```
select 'Sales > 50,000' as sales,
       count(*)         as qty
       where sales > 50000
union all
select 'Sales <  2,000' as sales,
       count(*)         as qty
       where sales < 2000
union all
select 'Sales > 15,000' as sales,
       count(*)         as qty
       where sales > 15000 and sales <= 50000
```

Note that last one, I'm assuming you want it *exclusive* from those above `50,000` (otherwise a row with `sales` of `60,000` shows up in both sections).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will try this and let you know. Appreciate your quick response, you saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(A),
  SUM(B),
  SUM(C)
FROM
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN Sales > 50000
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS A,
    CASE
      WHEN Sales < 2000
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS B,
    CASE
      WHEN Sales > 15000
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS C
  FROM table
  )
```